# RE: Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMjiD.png)

Ok so what I would like to do is Discount the value in cell M141 based on the value in C141. Example

If the value in C141 is between 10-19, then I would like to discount the value in M141 by 5%
If the value is between 20-29, then discount by 10%
If the value is between 30-39, then discount by 15%

Also, I would like the new discounted value to be entered into cell M140

Thank you and if you have any other questions, please ask!!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
=ifs(and((c141>9),(c141<20)),(m141-(m141*0.05)),and((c141>19),(c141<30)),(m141-(m141*0.1)),and((c141>29),(c141<40)),(m141-(m141*0.15)))
```

try this formula in the cell M140

Comment: you can also add an iferror function to get null if the conditions are false

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer might not work correctly. Please try the below formula if the previous one doesn't work

```
=IF(AND((C141>9),(C141<20)),(M141-(M141*0.05)),IF(AND((C141>19),(C141<30)),(M141-(M141*0.1)),IF(AND((C141>29),(C141<40)),(M141-(M141*0.15)),"No Discount")))
```

Please paste the formula M140. The "No Discount" indicates that the the C141 value does not fit in any of the desired criteria. You could tune it based on your requirements. Let me know if you need any help.